# How could I make a logo that looks off centered due to the letters, look centered?

Tags: logo, png

so I have my "brand" logo here, in a square, it looks perfectly fine, or at least pretty fine.
[image]

But, if I put it into a circle, it looks very off-center due to the U having a sharp edge, and the D having a rounded edge.
[image]

Is there anyway I can make it look on-center, or a good way to try to find out the amount it needs to be moved, etc, to make it look on-center? I've been able to make it look slightly on-center, but I can still tell it's off.

Comment: Even in the square view, the UHD can be nudged to the right a little.

Comment: Yea, I probably agree, I'm going to try to center it again soon.

Comment: Change the name of the company?

Comment: When it comes to optical adjustments, you just have to do it by eye. A good trick is to rotate or flip the image upside down: that way you'll see things as shapes instead of focusing on letters.

Comment: It's a YouTube channel, and I'm not a good name maker, and I currently like this one.

Comment: The best way to find out the amount it needs to be moved is simply to jiggle it in a graphics, not a type-setting app.

In this particular instance you might get somewhere by changing the kerning, the letter-spacing or even the horizontal scale of the individual letters… most obviously, the "I" or "T" in "BITS."

Please remember, it takes a skilled professional a week or two to design a type-face and even though "UHD" might have been, "BITS" almost certainly wasn't meant to be used that way…

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's already said that the space between the U and the circle should be equal with the space between the D and the circle. Move the items until they look right is, of course, how to fix the visual imbalance. But how to measure the space and adjust it if one wants a crutch to lean on? Here's one idea. It assumes the shortest distances should be the same.

[image]

1. Draw 2 thin circles to the most cramped points of the text. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to be able to start from the center of the original circle. Have Smart Guides and Snap to Point =ON to find the center. You must draw the circles approximately, it needs extra work to make them snap to the text,
2. Move the text to right with an arrow key until both cramped points are in the middle of the gap. Set small enough arrow key increment in the preferences. Count how many ticks it took.
3. Moving UHD and its counterpart XXXX together is a must because obviously XXXX must be aligned with UHD. But it seems to happen that XXXX looks like it is too far in the right when compared to the circle.
4. Moving XXXX back half of the number of used ticks seems to fix the problem as a compromise.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for the help, I'll try it once I can, I don't think there could be anything more helpful on measuring this.

Answer (score 14):

The reason it looks off-centre is because the left corner of the U is much closer to the edge of the circle than the top right of the letter D. This makes it feel imbalanced to the human eye/brain.

[image]

What I would do is adjust it using your eyes until it feels centred, by nudging only the UHD part to the right slightly. Obviously it will no longer be geometrically centred, but it will feel right. The human brain is easily fooled.

Something like this perhaps

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! This is the method I have been using, and it does work, but I've been looking for a method to more exactly get it more centered. Also, now the bits looks off centered from the UHD. I've found that just moving the bits with the UHD makes it look more centered anyways. The answer above is more like I was looking for.

Comment: The problem with "exact methods" is that is not how the human brain sees or interprets things in the real world. On many occasions it will lead to over-correction.  Optical balance in logo design is too subjective a subject. Manual adjustment by eye is the way to go. Learn instead to trust your eyes and brain, and stop stressing over geometry. The brain is organic, not a machine.

Answer (score 1):

Different left and right whitespace create an optical imbalance, even if this is probably centered geometrically. As Billy Kerr mentioned, you need to optically correct this by slightly shifting the UHD to the right. You'll lose the geometric alignment, but it will look more balanced overall.

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing looks heavy on the left adding to that fact is the slightly angled word "bits" further emphasizing the left optically plus the negative space of the letter U compared to the H actually makes the former to wide. Editing the negative space of the letter U to resemble that of H would probably work in itself creating a more centered UHD.